# Configuring U16 as a KVM host on laptop with no eth port

Tags: networking, laptop, kvm-virtualization

I have a DELL UPS15 which has no NIC. I have a USB to Ethernet adapter which I use at home and a USB-C dock which I use at work. Both signal different ethernet devices. I am running NetworkManager.

I am looking for ways of confuring a bridge so that I can run KVM guests continuously as I move my laptop across different network connections - this can mean different Wifi connections or the two different ethernet devices or possible no WAN access, just access between the guests. When I'm in the middle of something I don't want to have to go change my network settings just to continue working.

I've had it working in one (wired) place via Virtual Machine Manager and I've done it with NMTUI and an IPTables rule but I've been unable to achieve it dynamically. My best source for inspiration so far has been https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kvm-bridged.html

Has anyone solved this conundrum? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to bridge to an external physical interface? You could just create an internal virtual network or use the `default` one.

Comment: Despite being able to run an lab via internal only networking (ie between KVM guests) I have to get code etc onto the VMs. There are alternate options I know but being able to clone a git repo is so much easier with network access. Yup, sometimes, on a portable device I won't have WAN access, but I really don't want to be continuously rebuilding my networking just because I've changed location.

Comment: OK, so why not use the `default` NAT network or your own created NAT network?

Comment: Michael's suggestion of using the default NAT network works fine so long as I don't swap networking interfaces without restarting the VM. If I start a KVM instance using default NAT whilst using Wifi, it remains useable even when I switch Wifi networks. If I plug into an ethernet device it still works so long as the Wifi network also remains active. However, if I start up the VM with and ethernet connection and then remove it, I have to restart the KVM network before it returns to being usable in Wifi mode. If have tried to force the default NAT network to only use Wifi but no success yet.